# Get type definition for props.dispatch() for using TypeScript with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, tsc

I have this functional/stateless component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useFormik} from 'formik';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

function mapStateToProps(){
  return {
     foo: "bar"
  }
}

interface OwnProps {
  propFromParent: number
}


type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>
type Props = StateProps & OwnProps


const SignupForm = (props: Props) => {


  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: '',
      name: '',
      password: ''
    },
    onSubmit(values) {
      props.dispatch()   // props.dispatch is not defined!
    }
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="name">Full Name</label>
      <input
        id="name"
        name="name"
        type="name"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.name}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default connect<StateProps, null, Props>(mapStateToProps)(SignupForm);
```

so I am getting this compile error:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So how can I include the type definition so that props.dispatch is defined?
Just looking for help with the proper TS definitions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add a new function and pass it to connect() as second argument

```
...
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch): IDispatchProps {
 return {
  dispatch
 };
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

Comment: Yes this is the best solution.  You can just use  `ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>`, you don't need `IDispatchProps`

Comment: it is my habit. I always describe interfaces manually :) will try your way also. Ty :)

Comment: Note that the `ReturnType<typeof mapDispatch>` approach won't always work if you're using thunks, which is one reason why we specifically recommend the approach in our docs that I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [React-Redux docs on "Static Typing"](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing), which show how to handle defining the correct types for what `connect` will pass into your component.

Specifically, we recommend using the `ConnectedProps<T>` helper, like this:

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

interface RootState {
  isOn: boolean
}

const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
  isOn: state.isOn
})

const mapDispatch = {
  toggleOn: () => ({ type: 'TOGGLE_IS_ON' })
}

const connector = connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)

// The inferred type will look like:
// {isOn: boolean, toggleOn: () => void}
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

interface Props extends PropsFromRedux {
  backgroundColor: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}>
    <button onClick={props.toggleOn}>
      Toggle is {props.isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  </div>
)

export default connector(MyComponent)
```